# Get all strings matching pattern in text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get from text all strings which are between `t("` and `")` or `t('` and `')`.

I came up with regexp `/[^t\(("|\')]*(?=("|\')\))/`, but it is not ignoring character 't' when it is not before to '('.

For example:

```
$str  = 'This is a text, t("string1"), t(\'string2\')';
preg_match_all('/[^t\(("|\')]*(?=("|\')\))/', $str, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

returns `ring1` and `ring2`, but I need to get `string1` and `string2`.

You can consider [this](http://www.regexr.com/3ah51) also.

Comment: Is it `)"` and `)'` or `")` and `')`?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE seems like a typo..

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, sorry, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use separate regex for each.

```
(?<=t\(").*?(?="\))|(?<=t\(\').*?(?='\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rO3kJ1/3)

**Code:**

```
$re = "/(?<=t\\(\").*?(?=\"\\))|(?<=t\\(\\').*?(?='\\))/m";
$str = "This is a text, t(\"string1\"), t('string2')";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

**OR**

Use capturing group along with `\K`

```
t\((['"])\K.*?(?=\1\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rO3kJ1/4)

`\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in few steps with this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~t\((?|"([^"\\\]*+(?s:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*+)"\)|\'([^\'\\\]*+(?s:\\\.[^\'\\\]*)*+)\'\))~';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches))
    print_r($matches[1]);
```

It is a little long and repetitive, but it is fast and can deal with escaped quotes.

details:

```
t\(
(?|                 # Branch reset feature allows captures to have the same number
    "
    (               # capture group 1
        [^"\\]*+    # all that is not a double quote or a backslash
        (?s:        # non capturing group in singleline mode
            \\.     # an escaped character
            [^"\\]* # all that is not a double quote or a backslash
        )*+         
    )
    "\)
  |  # OR the same with single quotes (and always in capture group 1)
    '([^'\\]*+(?s:\\.[^'\\]*)*+)'\)
)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA4yN2/1)